# Recaptcha with Ajax error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, recaptcha

I'm having trouble validating a recaptcha input. Heres my code:

```
// Validate Recaptcha Input
var challenge = $("#recaptcha_challenge_field").val();
var response = $("#recaptcha_response_field").val();

var dataString = 'recaptcha_challenge_field=' + challenge + '&recaptcha_response_field=' + response;


var html = $.ajax({
type: "POST",
    url: "PHP/recaptchaverify.php",
    data: dataString,
    async: true
}).responseText;

console.log(html);

if(html == 'accept') 
{
    alert("CORRECT");
}

else
{
    alert("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again.");
    $("#recaptcha_response_field").focus();
    Recaptcha.reload();
    return false;
}
```

Now I passed my variables to recpatchaverify.php

```
require_once('../scripts/recaptcha-php/recaptchalib.php');
$privatekey = "MYKEY";

$resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey, $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"], $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

if (!$resp->is_valid) 
{
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
    echo "error";
} 

else 
{
    // Your code here to handle a successful verification
    echo "accept";
}
```

Now my problem is the html variable is displaying "accept" whenever I enter the Recaptcha correctly, but it won't work in the IF statement?

Comment: do you get .responseText correct?

Comment: yes, .responseText is displaying the error and accept variables correctly. Its just getting it past the if else statements.

Comment: if(html == "accept")  <<< that doesn't work

Comment: Try `data: {recaptcha_challenge_field:challenge, recaptcha_response_field: response},` instead of `data: dataString,`

Comment: Tried that, still same problem.

Comment: first why arent you using a callback instead?

Comment: Nevermind! solved. Turns out I had to trim the whitespace from the html variable. It works fine now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing an asynchronous request to the server, which means that when the $.ajax() line completes and execution continues onto the console.log() and if() statements, the actual request to the server is still pending and has not completed yet. At the time the if() statement executes, responseText is actually 'undefined'.

Instead, you need to use the 'success' callback function, like this:

```
// Validate Recaptcha Input
var challenge = $("#recaptcha_challenge_field").val();
var response = $("#recaptcha_response_field").val();

var dataString = 'recaptcha_challenge_field=' + challenge + '&recaptcha_response_field=' + response;


$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "PHP/recaptchaverify.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(html) {
        if(html == 'accept') 
        {
            alert("CORRECT");
        }

        else
        {
            alert("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again.");
            $("#recaptcha_response_field").focus();
            Recaptcha.reload();
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```